# JSPM + Cordova + Android

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, jspm

I get the following error when using JSPM CDN JavaScript, Cordova 5.1.1, TypeScript and Android:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
system@0.16.js (0,0)`

[image]

I took the default VS2015 TypeScript Cordova project and added the following to index.html:
`<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>`

The sample code has been tested on Windows Phone and works. I have tried Android API 19 and 22, physical devices and Genymotion(emulator).  Domain Access URI has been set to *.

Any ideas on why this would be happening only on Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  Here's the fix:

Add the custom plugin `cordova-plugin-whitelist` to the project.  It can be downloaded here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist

I also had to add the following code to the `<head>` tag in index.html.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https: 'self' jspm.io; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://jspm.io">`

If there's a better approach, please add an answer.

Comment: You can find more information about Cordova 5 and security features and configuration here: http://aka.ms/cordova5security